# HTTPS proxies does not work when sending requests

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I want to crawl some websites with Python and BeautifulSoup lib, and I want to set some proxies. I came a cross a problem with setting up the proxies.
When ever I set https proxy, it does not work, but when i set the http proxy it works.
Do you know whats the problem?

```
import requests

https_proxies = [{'https': 'https://60.191.11.241:3128'},
                  {'https': 'https://129.226.162.177:80'},
                  {'https': 'https://103.231.80.202:55443'},
                  {'https': 'https://167.172.171.115:34538'},
                  {'https': 'https://103.104.193.34:6000'},
                  {'https': 'https://200.60.4.238:999'}]

for proxy in https_proxies:
  try:
    r1 = requests.get("https://edition.cnn.com/", proxies=proxy, timeout = 3)
    print(r1)
  except:
    print("BAD PROXY")

http_proxies = [{'http': 'http://194.169.164.14:34334'},
                {'http': 'http://46.167.238.109:5678'},
                {'http': 'http://201.59.102.35:5678'},
                {'http': 'http://31.25.243.40:9147'},
                {'http': 'http://178.162.202.44:1025'}]

for proxy in http_proxies:
  try:
    r1 = requests.get("https://edition.cnn.com/", proxies=proxy, timeout = 3)
    print(r1)
  except:
    print("BAD PROXY")
```

I have tried with more than 50 HTTPS proxies on 10 different websites, and its always the same.
This is the website I have used for getting the proxies:
https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list
And this:
https://free-proxy-list.net/

Comment: 1) missing colons after `http/https` 2) http and https are using different ports

Comment: Ok for colons, I have tried with and without colons and it works both way.
Can you explain me the 2) part? This is the website I have used for getting the proxies

https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list

Comment: @Marat I have used the proxies that are https allowed, and still they do not work

Comment: This means, you can't just change the proxy prefix to https and hope it works. It works for websites when port is not explicitly set, but only because browsers use a set of two default ports. Thus, just by looking at the same proxy+port combination reused, it could not possibly work

Comment: Once you use a set of actual HTTPS proxies, it works. Note that a different exception will be thrown if the proxy is not HTTPS, and if it simply doesn't work. Most of the public proxies are disfunctional (will throw `ConnectionTimeout`), but some actually work. No changes to code are required, just a different set of proxies and perhaps a more selective `except`

Comment: @Marat I understand what you want to say, but even if I set the list of proxies that are https (not the same as http), I get the same error. I get that I have gave maybe bad example but please check the question, I have updated the list of proxies. If you go to: https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list , you can chose if you want http or https, and if I select HTTPS none of the proxies work. Thats very strange for me because I have tried with 50 http proxies and they ALL work, and I have tired with 100 different HTTPS proxies and none of them work

Comment: I did exactly the same (same proxy list, filtered by HTTPS only), but one out of the four proxies I tried actually worked. Oh, and I also increased timeout to 10 seconds, just in case